# How can i pass a non specific class to sub

Tags: vb.net

I have code which takes a Soap Response and serializes into a xml so i can write it to console. Code works great but as i am trying to clean up my code i am trying to stick the code into a sub so i can use it for different responses.

```
Dim Response As ATTSoapReference.ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP = newRequest.submitAddVal(ATT_ADDR)

    Dim serxml = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Response.GetType())
    Dim ms = New MemoryStream()
    serxml.Serialize(ms, Response)
    Dim xml As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())
    Console.WriteLine(xml)
```

If i want to do it as a sub for only this request type i can use

```
Private Sub DebugXML(byval myResponse As ATTSoapReference.ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP)
    Dim serxml = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(myResponse.GetType())
    Dim ms = New MemoryStream()
    serxml.Serialize(ms, myResponse)
    Dim xml As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())
    Console.WriteLine(xml)
End Sub
```

But i am looking for something that will allow me to pass any Soap Data Class to it instead of ATTSoapReference.ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP

Comment: ATTSoapReference.ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP inherits from a class.  View the class details (might be hidden).  See what the base class is.  That will be the type for your method's parameter.

Comment: And i guess Object is the best match since when i browse the Class i get. 
Public Class ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP
        Inherits Object
    Member of ATTSoapTest.ATTSoapReference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as said below and see if it works.

```
Private Sub DebugXML(byval myResponse As Object)

     'May be you require casting, for some specific things.

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that worked, it gave me the warning that myResponse.GetType() is a possible mistaken call to GetType() but i guess that would be expected as one can pass any object and GetType might be not avail.